# Sonata Admin - default_locale overwritten by fallback

Tags: sonata-admin, sonata

I'm trying to set Sonata pages locale to different value than my main application.

I have in my `config.yml`:

```
    parameters:
        locale: ru
    framework:
        translator: { fallbacks: ["%locale%"] }
    sonata_translation:
        locales: [en, de]
        default_locale: en
```

I expected to have main page in Russian and admin pages in English, but all pages are in Russian.

How can I change default language of Sonata Admin pages?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As far as I know, there's no such parameter **sonata_translation**. Sonata Admin does not have any locale/translation configuration parameters: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/admin/master/doc/reference/configuration.html

Sonata uses your application/session locale. What you can/should do, is **set locale for authorized user** and user will have his session in preferred language.

Comment: I have `sonata-project/translation-bundle` bundle installed, it's configured as described in https://sonata-project.org/bundles/translation/master/doc/reference/installation.html

Comment: This bundle has nothing to do with translating Sonata Admin interface. This bundle provides translatable interface for your models. If you want to have a Blog Post admin with translatable title/article fields - this bundle can help you save time. But as of application interface - see my answer. UPDATE: the bundle has a description as well: https://sonata-project.org/bundles/translation/master/doc/index.html Don't just rely on bundle names, read some docs at least...